# How to get next Auto Increment value from specific table

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have **customer** table with *Auto Incremented - primary key column* - **cust_Id**

For some reason I need to know the next cust_Id in my system

So how to find it?
**What is the query ?**

p.s. - I tried this **SELECT  ident_current('dbo.SomeTable') AS [LastID_1];**
but its not supported.

Answer (score 0):

See the link here. You should also add the increment value

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d346672-4ad4-4a82-acf8-de392706a959/get-the-next-value-of-identity

Answer (score 0):

```
select (max( ident_current('dbo.SomeTable')) + 1) AS [Next_id]
```

Comment: This Error Occurs :  
The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name =  ]

Comment: Now I edited the last comment.. on round braces was misplaced

Comment: Now The Error Is : The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact Edition :(

Comment: best way is you make a new table which contains only last value of ident_current..

According to me Compact edition of SQL doesn't support trigger 
you download the addon from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22875
I will explain you how

create table lastcustvalue ( ident_current int);

then create a trigger which always store updated value in this table.. so table will contain 1 row and 1 column allways as it contains only updated values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(youridfieldname+1) As NextId FROM "yourtable name"
```

for e.g
if your field name is ID and your table name is Table1 :

> `SELECT Max(ID+1) AS NextID
>   FROM Table1;`

Comment: this is erroneous in the case: If i have recently deleted last row
(the record with maximum ID).